# thrift building java library ......:no

Tags: thrift

I install thrift just following the instruction on http://thrift.apache.org/docs/install/centos

After running the ./configure command I got:

```
Building C++ Library ......... : yes
Building C (GLib) Library .... : no
**Building Java Library ........ : no**
Building C# Library .......... : no
Building Python Library ...... : no
Building Ruby Library ........ : no
Building Haxe Library ........ : no
Building Haskell Library ..... : no
Building Perl Library ........ : no
Building PHP Library ......... : yes
Building Erlang Library ...... : no
Building Go Library .......... : no
Building D Library ........... : no
Building NodeJS Library ...... : no
Building Lua Library ......... : no

C++ Library:
   Build TZlibTransport ...... : yes
   Build TNonblockingServer .. : yes
   Build TQTcpServer (Qt4) .... : no
   Build TQTcpServer (Qt5) .... : no

PHP Library:
   Using php-config .......... :
```

I have installed java and ant

```
[root@localhost thrift]# java -version
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)
```

I don't understand why the 'building java library is no'

Comment: You should use Maven or Gradle to handle your dependencies, and then there's no need to build Thrift anyway.

Answer (score 10):

If you have not installed Ant, install it first and run ./configure again.

Answer (score 1):

As of Thrift 0.10.0, it expects Ant version 1.7 or newer. However, it doesn't detect Ant 1.10.1 as valid version. I had to downgrade to Ant 1.9.9 to compile Thrift with Java support.

Answer (score 0):

First, the configure script writes a very detailed log file (which BTW is mentioned at the end of the configure step). The reason should be deductable from that info.

The second thing that comes to my mind is this: I have seen problems with the Java path on non-english locales, there's even a [ticket about it](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-1787).

With what we have above it is hard to tell much more.

Answer (score 0):

Confirm @Ken Block's answer:

From https://thrift.apache.org/docs/install/ :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was using mac OS, for me I installed ant and reran that configure script to get the java package.

```
brew install ant

# and then 

./configure
```